# Using Asp.Net MVC with SharePoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Is it possible to use the Asp.Net MVC framework within SharePoint sites?

Comment: Ashish Sharma you have to mark some answer as a correct one.

Comment: Have a look here as well http://www.interah.com/products/Documents/Items%20Selector.pdf

Answer (score 21):

In ScottGu's [blog from February 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/02/12/asp-net-mvc-framework-road-map-update.aspx), he writes:

> Currently MVC doesn't directly
>   integrate with SharePoint.  That is
>   something we'll be looking at
>   supporting in the future though.

There's a project on CodePlex for getting ASP.NET MVC to work in SharePoint:
http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointMVC

Answer (score 21):

This might be of interest to you http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointMVC

It is basically a library to help rendering ASP.MVC inside a SharePoint masterpage.

Still early days but you get the idea.

Answer (score 13):

The following sharepoint site, www.themedicinecabinet.co.uk, was built using ASP.net MVC 2. This article explains how this was done
http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf

Comment: +10! I have looked at the start of the article, and it looks very, very promising. The author writes with apparent deep understanding of all the relevant issues. I hope to follow it through and implement it, and post back here to confirm my initial impressions, but that will be some time.

Comment: +1 Very impressive, in depth example of how to fully integrate ASP.Net MVC 2 with a SharePoint site and access the resources of SharePoint from within MVC. Kudos.

Comment: This link is dead but that one we have still to check amd joy http://jcapka.blogspot.com/2011/02/asp-mvc-and-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 4):

One possible architecture is to use an asp.net or an asp.net mvc frontend. Then accessing sharepoint functionality via web services.

This has the benefit of giving you access to the functionality of sharepoint, without having the extra development cost of using sharepoint.

Comment: I was wondering about this logic myself. Are there any examples of using WSS web services in a .Net MVC application?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so, although you can upload standard ASPX files into SharePoint and have them operate I'm pretty sure that the URL rewritting is where it would come unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is create sharepoint "powered" apps with asp.net mvc just by referencing the SharePoint assembly.

I guess the Sharepoint Object Model would be your M in MVC.