# "ASP.NET MVC" CMS in Sharepoint Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, content-management-system, sharepoint-api

I'm evaluating the options for a CMS in ASP.NET MVC. I'm currently working on a multi-tenant app that requires CMS functionality. I've been looking at N2, Mojoportal etc, but I'm also interested in what SharePoint Services could bring to the table. Specifically I don't want a SharePoint site but rather I'd like to potentially use the sharepoint object model, db tables, etc. to form the core of the CMS.

Is this possible with SharePoint or am I going down the wrong path? I've not had much experience with it.

Comment: Have you checked out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816/using-asp-net-mvc-with-sharepoint

Comment: Have you looked at OrchardCMS. It's based on ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint is not an ASP.NET MVC application, it's all web forms. There is the [SharePointMVC](http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointMVC) CodePlex project that attempts to bring MVC to SharePoint.

At the end of the day you are very likely to need to follow the 'web forms' way of doing things sooner or later with SharePoint. So if MVC is a requirement I would not use SharePoint. However your requirements should probably be around what the customers want, not what technology to use?

I also wouldn't take the approach of using SharePoint's back end only. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407042/sharepoint-authentication-for-access-by-a-web-app) for some good reasons why.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is built on top of ASP.NET