# Building pages with multiple views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to build an ASP.NET MVC application where many screens will have multiple distinct views. Ideally the user would be able to bring the items they require into their workspace page in a portal style. Even if that is not possible, there would need to be a number of common items joined in various ways for various classes of user: something difficult to achieve with traditional inheritance.

It seems to me that the URL structure allows for only one controller to instantiated and for this to bring up one view at a time (and only one) - not place multiple views on a page.  Searching here I have seen reference to MVC Contrib subcontrollers, but I can't see them on the http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib site to check them out any further?

Would subcontrollers be the way to go ?  If so, where do I find them now. If not, what would you suggest ?

Comment: Are you maybe referring to **web parts** when you talk about *pages with multiple views*?

Comment: I'm referring to something like web parts: but each part would have its own controller. Model ViewViewView ControllerControllerController M(VC)n ???  type thing where perhaps controllers can message each other, but certainly not act on each others views. Similar to the (ghastly) concept of dropping several iframes, each pointing to its own MVC URL on one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with using asp.net mvc then you can work with partial views which will/should give you the "web part" type functionality which it sounds like you want. You can then limit the which partial views you want to see depending on permissions etc. on the main page views (this could be exposed via a base controller class or something).

I've done a little searching and have come up with a few links which you might find useful ...

[Jeffrey Palermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/) - Talks about templating partial views

[Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-using-usercontrols-usefully/) - using user controls with asp.net mvc

[mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels) - ASP.NET MVC Partial Views and Strongly Typed Custom ViewModels (not read all of this, but it looks pretty usefu)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to go this route. Partial views will work well enough, but its a shame that its going to need a fat controller - it would have been nice to separate out the controller logic into the entities that they control.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the futures assembly and it's implementation of RenderAction(). Although it's not pure MVC, these can basically be used as widgets. They are called from a view and go through a separate controller which then renders a partial view. This sounds like what you may be looking for.

Here's an example...

```
//Various view data

<div id="user-info">
    <% Html.RenderAction("UserInfo"); %>
</div>

//Rest of view data
```

This will look for an action method named "UserInfo" on the current controller. That controller can then do what it need to do, and send it's results to a partial view that will be rendered in place of the Html.RenderAction().

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are not bound to any particular views. Depending on your business logic, a controller/action can display any view you want.

**EDIT**
You could always try writing [HtmlHelpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) and partial views. These are what you should use instead of webforms' server controls and user controls respectively.

Comment: The issue is that I need to show multiple things with independent behaviour on a single page. Ideally this would be multiple views with multiple independent controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are taking about 2 different things:

- Adding items on the page is web parts not asp.net mvc
- There is no problem using a controller to choose which view to show, but only one can be shown at a time.

**EDIT**

What you are looking to do requires both sharepoint and asp.net mvc. It is possible to combined these, see: [Using Asp.Net MVC with SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816/using-asp-net-mvc-with-sharepoint)

Comment: I've edited the question to try to clarify. I am looking to do something similar to webparts with ASP.NET MVC. I understand that the controller can choose which view to show. It can't choose multiple views, nor can there be multiple controllers and views contributing to the same page: which is what I would like!