# asp.net mvc and sharepoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am working with asp.net mvc. I hate asp.net webforms. Sharepoint works only with asp.net webforms. Do you have any information about where Sharepoint will have an edition written in asp.net MVC ?

Comment: Check out [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816/using-asp-net-mvc-with-sharepoint), the situation doesn't appear to have changed.

Comment: i asked about the time microsoft will integrate it, so the question is different

Comment: So that makes it a non-programming question which isn't relevant on SO. *However*, the second answer in that thread links to Scott Gu's blog which mentions that it may be planned for the future.

Answer (score 1):

yeah it looks like it is possible to put the two of the together http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2012/07/building-aspnet-mvc-based-sharepoint.html